# Получение значения переменной по таймеру

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Дана переменная, нужно обновлять ее значение раз в секунду, как это реализовать на JQuery?

Comment: @RomanAnanev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Код без Jquery, но Вам ничто не мешает использовать данный код где угодно:

```
var s = 0;
function func() {
 s++;
 alert('Привет'+s);
}
setInterval(func, 1000); //Будет выполнять код каждую секунду.
setTimeout(func,1000);   //Выполнит код 1 раз через 1 секунду.
```

Если очень надо именно через Jquery, то можете [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/42809/) посмотреть. Но это потянет за собой подключение дополнительной библиотеки, поэтому 10 раз подумайте. Лучше внутри Вашего Jquery кода использовать выше приведенный код.

Comment: только один момент - обычно лучше не setInterval(), а setTimeout()
Он добавляет своеобразную рекурсию, конечно, но зато с ним проще работать новичкам, т.к. не возникает вопроса "Как это остановить" :-)

Comment: @StixoTvorec, да, лучше для начала setTimeout().А если и интервально, то раз в 5 секунд хотя бы (по крайней мере этот пример). :)

Comment: @ilja угу. Вспомнил свою первую отладку... Естественно alert'ом, естественно в цикле. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Много раз уже говорилось, что JS таймеры (`setInterval(), setTimeout()`) — не точны, причём заметно. Поэтому лучше вызывать ф-ю почаще, и смотреть на часы. [Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/2oub51pa/).

```
var x = 42; // та самая переменная

var BigBen = new Date(); // это часы
function tiktak() {
    if( (Date.now() - BigBen.getTime()) < 1000) return; // ещё не прошло 1 сек

    x -= 1; // например, будем уменьшать на 1 каждую секунду
    BigBen.setTime( Date.now()); // обновить время на «сейчас»
}
var timer = window.setInterval( tiktak, 1000/100); // точность 1/100 секунды. Можно и точнее.

// остановить таймер потом можно так:
// window.clearInterval( timer);
```